# Will this conflict with prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page using prototype (don't have much control over that).

What I'd like to do is have a document ready function that only uses "jQuery" once, and then inside that function I can just use `$` and it won't conflict with prototype.

This is what I have so far

```
jQuery(function() {
    var superProperties = $.cookie('mp_' + token + '_mixpanel');
    console.log($.cookie());
});
```

Comment: Change `jQuery(function() {` to `jQuery(function($) {`. jQuery passes the jQuery function as an argument to the callback.

Comment: ...but why use two big libraries? There's lots of overlap, so why not just use one or the other?

Comment: it's outside my control. This is on a 3rd party shopping cart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to run on document load

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var superProperties = $.cookie('mp_' + token + '_mixpanel');
    console.log($.cookie());
});
```

If you want it to run immediately

```
(function($) {
    var superProperties = $.cookie('mp_' + token + '_mixpanel');
    console.log($.cookie());
})(jQuery);
```